# How to add a column with specific values in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have been looking to set up a simple code to scratch data from the web. The result is a list of dataframes in a list. What I am trying to do is to add specific informations for each of the dataframes, in order to bind them afterwards.

Here is the code

`page_numbers <- c(123, 124, 125, 126)`

```
urls <- paste("http://www.abstimmungen.bl.ch/de/vote/detail/", page_numbers, sep = "")

Data <- lapply(urls, function(x){readHTMLTable(getURL(x),stringsAsFactors=F)})
```

Nothing let me distinguish the differents dataframes. I thought therefore to make a list of name as following

```
Title <- list("Bruderholz-Initiative", "Lehrpersonen-Initiative", "Abschaffung Amtszeitbeschränkung", "Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden")
```

I want to add the same column variable to all the dataframe, called Title, and add the specific value for each of them with a loop for.

```
for( i in Data){
  Data[[i]]$Titre <- rep(Titre[i],
                         nrow(as.data.frame(Data[[i]]))
                         )}
```

The result is an error because of an incorrect indice. 
Alternatively, I have tried this other piece of code

```
Data2 <- Map(transform , Data, Titres = Titre[i])
```

I really don't see how to correct my code to make it works, I can only guess that the structure of my list cause a problem. Any help is really welcome 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The OP's goal is *to add specific informations for each of the dataframes, in order to bind them afterwards.*

The sample data provided by the OP suggest that it's only one item, `Title`, that should be added, presumably for later grouping. If this is the case, there is a simple solution at hand using `rindlist()` from the `data.table` package which "names" the rows while binding:

```
# remove one list level to get a list of data.frames
# (as already suggested by the OP)
Data1 <- unlist(Data, recursive = FALSE)
# name the list elements
Data1 <- setNames(Data1, Title)
str(Data1)
```

> ```
> List of 4
>  $ Bruderholz-Initiative           :'data.frame': 91 obs. of  9 variables:
>   ..$ Bezirk   : chr [1:91] "Bezirk Arlesheim" "Aesch" "Allschwil" "Arlesheim" ...
>   ..$ Resultat : chr [1:91] "abgelehnt11680" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" ...
>   ..$ Ja       : chr [1:91] "15433" "840" "1473" "727" ...
>   ..$ Nein     : chr [1:91] "27159" "1606" "3513" "1982" ...
>   ..$ Leer     : chr [1:91] "864" "38" "121" "75" ...
>   ..$ UngÃ¼ltig: chr [1:91] "758" "18" "179" "59" ...
>   ..$ Ja%      : chr [1:91] "36.23" "34.34" "29.54" "26.84" ...
>   ..$ Nein%    : chr [1:91] "63.77" "65.66" "70.46" "73.16" ...
>   ..$ Gemeldet : chr [1:91] "15 von 15" "ja" "ja" "ja" ...
>  $ Lehrpersonen-Initiative         :'data.frame': 91 obs. of  9 variables:
> [...]
>  $ Abschaffung Amtszeitbeschränkung:'data.frame': 91 obs. of  9 variables:
> [...]
>  $ Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden  :'data.frame': 91 obs. of  9 variables:
> [...]
> ```

```
library(data.table)
# combine all rows, thereby creating an id column Title containing 
# the names of the list elements 
DT <- rbindlist(Data1, idcol = "Title")
DT
```

> ```
>                               Title           Bezirk       Resultat    Ja  Nein Leer UngÃ¼ltig   Ja% Nein%  Gemeldet
>   1:          Bruderholz-Initiative Bezirk Arlesheim abgelehnt11680 15433 27159  864       758 36.23 63.77 15 von 15
>   2:          Bruderholz-Initiative            Aesch      abgelehnt   840  1606   38        18 34.34 65.66        ja
>   3:          Bruderholz-Initiative        Allschwil      abgelehnt  1473  3513  121       179 29.54 70.46        ja
>   4:          Bruderholz-Initiative        Arlesheim      abgelehnt   727  1982   75        59 26.84 73.16        ja
>   5:          Bruderholz-Initiative      Biel-Benken      abgelehnt   565   575   23        20 49.56 50.44        ja
>  ---                                                                                                                
> 360: Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden       Niederdorf     angenommen   298    85   15         4 77.81 22.19        ja
> 361: Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden         Oberdorf     angenommen   416   119   27         4 77.76 22.24        ja
> 362: Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden      Reigoldswil     angenommen   333    65   23         7 83.67 16.33        ja
> 363: Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden        Titterten     angenommen   122    28    9         4 81.33 18.67        ja
> 364: Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden       Waldenburg     angenommen   158    45   23         4 77.83 22.17        ja
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, there are also other ways to add an id column to the single data rows *before* binding:

In the original, nested list:

```
Data0 <- lapply(seq_along(Data), function(.i) cbind(Data[[.i]][[1]], Title = Title[[.i]]))
str(Data0[1])
```

> ```
> List of 1
>  $ :'data.frame': 91 obs. of  10 variables:
>   ..$ Bezirk   : chr [1:91] "Bezirk Arlesheim" "Aesch" "Allschwil" "Arlesheim" ...
>   ..$ Resultat : chr [1:91] "abgelehnt11680" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" ...
>   ..$ Ja       : chr [1:91] "15433" "840" "1473" "727" ...
>   ..$ Nein     : chr [1:91] "27159" "1606" "3513" "1982" ...
>   ..$ Leer     : chr [1:91] "864" "38" "121" "75" ...
>   ..$ UngÃ¼ltig: chr [1:91] "758" "18" "179" "59" ...
>   ..$ Ja%      : chr [1:91] "36.23" "34.34" "29.54" "26.84" ...
>   ..$ Nein%    : chr [1:91] "63.77" "65.66" "70.46" "73.16" ...
>   ..$ Gemeldet : chr [1:91] "15 von 15" "ja" "ja" "ja" ...
>   ..$ Title    : Factor w/ 1 level "Bruderholz-Initiative": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> ```

or in the "flattened" list:

```
Data1 <- unlist(Data, recursive = FALSE)
Data2 <- lapply(seq_along(Data1), function(.i) cbind(Data1[[.i]], Title = Title[[.i]]))
str(Data2[1])
```

> ```
> List of 1
>  $ :'data.frame': 91 obs. of  10 variables:
>   ..$ Bezirk   : chr [1:91] "Bezirk Arlesheim" "Aesch" "Allschwil" "Arlesheim" ...
>   ..$ Resultat : chr [1:91] "abgelehnt11680" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" "abgelehnt" ...
>   ..$ Ja       : chr [1:91] "15433" "840" "1473" "727" ...
>   ..$ Nein     : chr [1:91] "27159" "1606" "3513" "1982" ...
>   ..$ Leer     : chr [1:91] "864" "38" "121" "75" ...
>   ..$ UngÃ¼ltig: chr [1:91] "758" "18" "179" "59" ...
>   ..$ Ja%      : chr [1:91] "36.23" "34.34" "29.54" "26.84" ...
>   ..$ Nein%    : chr [1:91] "63.77" "65.66" "70.46" "73.16" ...
>   ..$ Gemeldet : chr [1:91] "15 von 15" "ja" "ja" "ja" ...
>   ..$ Title    : Factor w/ 1 level "Bruderholz-Initiative": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> ```

*No* kind of `for` loops is required to accomplish the task.

Please, note that `cbind()` has turned `Title` to factor by default. This can be turned off by including the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the call to `cbind()`.

Both approaches return a list of data.frames which can be directly combined row-wise by

```
do.call(rbind, Data0)
```

or

```
rbindlist(Data0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem of adding *Title* later, why not add *Title* within the apply loop when we read the url one by one, then rbind, see:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

page_numbers <- c(123, 124, 125, 126)
Title <- c("Bruderholz-Initiative", "Lehrpersonen-Initiative",
           "Abschaffung Amtszeitbeschränkung", "Aufgabenzuordnung BL-Gemeinden")

Data <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(seq(page_numbers),
                 function(x){
                   myURL <- paste("http://www.abstimmungen.bl.ch/de/vote/detail/", page_numbers[x], sep = "")
                   # above is returning a list, so take the first one...
                   dd <- readHTMLTable(getURL(myURL), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]]
                   dd$Title <- Title[x]
                   # return
                   dd
                 })
  )
```